# How to write a 2D array to a single column in Google Sheets, using Google Apps Script?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write the array to a single column, but despite everything seems right to me, it keeps throwing me an error:

Here's the piece of code:

```
function getGFTickersData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LIST OF STOCKS");
  var tickerRng = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  //var TDSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TickersData");
  var TDSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet10");
  var tickerArr = [];
  for (var b = 0; b < tickerRng.length; b++) {
    var tickerToArr = [tickerRng[b]];
    if (tickerToArr != '') {
      var gFinFormula = "=query(googlefinance(" + '"' + tickerToArr + '"' + ",'all shares'!A4,'all shares'!D3,'all shares'!D4,'all shares'!D5)," + '"' + "select *" + '"' + ",1)";
      var repeated = [].concat(... new Array(105).fill(tickerToArr))
      tickerArr.push(repeated)
    }
  }
  Logger.log(tickerArr[0]);
  TDSheet.getRange(TDSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, tickerArr.length, 1).setValues(tickerArr);
}
```

[image]

Appreciate any pointers!

Comment: In your script, `tickerArr` is 3 dimensional array. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this. But I cannot understand about your goal from your question. So I cannot propose the modification point of your script. I apologize for this. For example, when you want to put the value of `tickerArr[0]`, you can modify the last line to `TDSheet.getRange(TDSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, tickerArr[0].length, 1).setValues(tickerArr[0])`. But I'm not sure whether this is the result you expect. So, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike. The array is composed of about 200k element, each showing in the array 105 times. I want to write all of them, one on the top of the other in a single column. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your following replying,

> The array is composed of about 200k element, each showing in the array 105 times. I want to write all of them, one on the top of the other in a single column.

How about the following modification?

#### From:

```
tickerArr.push(repeated)
```

#### To:

```
tickerArr = tickerArr.concat(repeated);
```

#### References:

- [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)